# como vincular un url en un boton dentro de una funcion jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

con una funcion jquery lleno una tabla con los datos que necesito y tengo dentro de tabla dos botones uno para los detalles de ese elemento y el otro para editarlo  que me pemitiran acceder a una url dado el elemento listado en la tabla, como hago para vincular las urls a los botones y pasarle el id de ese elemento esta es una parte de la funcion :

```
$.post($(this).attr('data-url'), $(this).serializeArray(), function (data) {
                // console.log(data);
                table_busqueda_pregunta.clear().draw();
                data.forEach(function (pregunta){
                    table_busqueda_pregunta.row.add([
                        pregunta.descripcion,
                        pregunta.autor,
                        pregunta.fecha,
                        pregunta.nivel,
                        "<a class='btn btn-primary' style='margin-right: 10px;'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span></a>" +
                        "<a class='btn btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>"
                    ]).draw(false);
                });
                // console.log("Success!");


            }, 'json');
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que al dar clic al botón te dirija a una página?

Comment: `"<a class='btn btn-primary' href="+pregunta.infourl+" style='margin-right: 10px;'>"`?